# Finding an explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb R^4 / \ker \ T$ and $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: proof-verification, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm wondering if I have a valid answer to this.

It is exactly (e) of the following:

[image]

I first state that the two vector spaces are isomorphic because they have equal dimension. I then define a linear transform $S:  \mathbb R^4  / Ker  \ T \to \mathbb R^2$ by

$$S \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
a \\ 
b \\ 
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}  \to 
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\end{pmatrix}: a,b \in \mathbb R$$

Where $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
a \\ 
b \\ 
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ is an arbitrary element in the departure space.

If this mapping translates basis to basis, this is an isomorphism.

$$
S \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
a \\ 
b \\ 
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}  \to 
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^2 \implies S\left(a \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}  + 
b\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\right) = a \  \vec e_1 + b  \vec \ e_2 $$
$$
\text{ as
 $S\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$
S\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$}$$

Is this a valid answer?

Comment: What is $F$? Is it $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos an arbitrary field. I should’ve specified, my bad.

Comment: But you mention $\mathbb R$ in the title.

Comment: Yes, I’ll correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not valid, since you don't even mention $F^4/\ker T$ in it. An explicit isomorphism would be$$\begin{array}{rccc}\Psi\colon&F^4/\ker T&\longrightarrow&F^2\\&\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}+\ker T&\mapsto&T\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}.\end{array}$$

Comment: Forgive me, I’m confused. Can you explain in more detail why, if I did mention what I didn’t mention, why it’s still not a valid answer? An why yours is a valid explicit isomorphism?

Comment: FIrst of all, there are two maps called $T$ in your answer. Not a good idea. Besides, you just *claim* that the domain of your second $T$ is $F^4/\ker T$, but it is actually a subspace of $F^4$.

Comment: Oh, you’re right. This exercise was a follow up to a previous exercise with defined $T$ such that the quotient space ended up being what I represented. I will update the question presently with the missing info.